# org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException when I run my project

Tags: java, spring

Dao

```
public interface DictDao {
   void updateUserInfo(UserUser userUser);
}


@Repository(value = "dictDao")
public class DictDaoImpl<K extends Serializable, V extends Serializable> implements DictDao {

    @Autowired
    protected RedisTemplate<K, V> redisTemplate;

    @Override
    public void updateUserInfo(final UserUser userUser) {
    }
}
```

Service

```
@Service("userUserService")
public class UserUserServiceImpl implements UserUserService{

    @Resource
    private UserUserDao userUserDao;

    @Override
    public UserUser insertByHugId(String hugId, String partnerType) {
        UserUserDto dto = new UserUserDto();
        dto.setHgId(hugId);
        UserUser userUser = userUserMapper.select(dto);
        userUserDao.add(userUser,partnerType);
        return userUser;
    }
}
```

Spring Config
[enter image description here][5]
[enter image description here][6]

My Test

```
public class UserUserServiceImplTest {

    private ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context;

    private UserUserService userUserService;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:spring/spring-config.xml");
        userUserService = (UserUserService)context.getBean("userUserService");
    }

    @Test
    public void insertByHugId() throws Exception{
        userUserService.insertByHugId("LN13177109","52");
    }
}
```

appear this exception when I run my test:
org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'userUserDao' for bean class [com.lanniuh.manage.dao.user.redis.hug.UserUserDao] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [com.lanniuh.manage.dao.user.redis.hug.impl.UserUserDaoImpl]

please help me, much obliged.

Comment: Spring Config：include <context:component-scan base-package "com.lanniuh;"/> and the package="com.lanniuh;" is where my dao exists

Comment: Why are you showing us code for `DictDao`, `DictDaoImpl`, `UserUserServiceImpl`, and `UserUserServiceImplTest` when error message is about **`UserUserDao`** and **`UserUserDaoImpl`**? All useless. Edit the question, and delete everything except the error message, then format error message for human readability and add ***relevant*** code. *<sheesh>*

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/5221149)

Answer (score 0):

you can resolve this issue by removing the autowiring completely and accessing the bean by creating a reference to it through the application context and the getBean() method.

or you can use annotation on all classes and use below code into ApplicationContaxt.xml:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.package.*" />
```

and use the `@Autowired`.